# Hilbert spaces - equivalent norm

Tags: hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space with a norm $\| \cdot \|_1$. Let $\| \cdot \|_2$ be another norm on $H$ which is equivalent with $\| \cdot \|_1$. It is easy to see that $(H, \| \cdot \|_2)$ is a Banach space since the norms are equivalent. Is it also true that $(H, \| \cdot \|_2)$ is a Hilbert space? I think that the answer is no, but I cannot find a counterexample.

Comment: Consider $\ell_1^n$ and $\ell_2^n$.

Comment: This is not true even in the finite dimensional case. Take $\mathbb{C}^n$: There is a unique LCTVS topology. In particular, all $l^p$ norms, $1 \leq p \leq \infty$, are equivalent. But only one, $p=2$, is a Hilbert space norm.

Comment: Sure, I was silly. Thank you.

Comment: @Michael That's an answer, not a comment...

Answer (score 1):

Consider for example that on $\mathbb R^m$ all the norm are equivalent, and so $\ldots$